# Where is FrameworkUap10 used in VSTest.Console.exe for Win Universal Apps Unit testing

Tags: testing, tfs, uwp

I've been tasked with adding Unit Testing to our WinUA. The developer said he added a new unit test for UWP project to his solution and I'm to add calling this at build time. He wasn't sure how to do it and pointed me to this article: [Set up automated builds for your UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps)

I've added a "Visual Studio Test" step and set the following:

```
Test Assembly = **\*.UnitTests.build.appxrecipe
Other console options = /framework:FrameworkUap10
```

Running it throws the following error:

> [error]Error: Invalid .Net Framework version:FrameworkUap10. Supported .Net Framework versions are Framework35, Framework40 and Framework45.

If I remove the invalid framework, no error is thrown but also no tests are run.

I cannot find any information on the /framework:FrameworkUap10 option. Searched MS, here and web and all that comes up is its use in this article... nothing about installing it on the build machine.

How does one install FrameworkUap10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using the following using the following msbuild args for the msbuild step:

```
/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)"
/p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\AutoBuildPackages\"
/p:AppxBundle=Always
/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload
```

[image]